# custom phtml code not working in cms home page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block

here is my code which i have used in cms home page and created `phtml` in `app/design/frontend/theme/template/catalog/product/displayed.phtml`

```
{{block type="catalog/product_displayed" name="product_displayed" as="product_displayed" template="catalog/product/displayed.phtml}}
```

Comment: have you created any custom block like catalog/product_displayed?

Answer (score 1):

As from magento 1.9 and above

You need to white list your custom `blockcatalog/product_displayed`. This is required for **Magento 1.9 and greater.**

You do this in the backend: `System ->  permissions -> blocks`

I.e if you wish to show:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_displayed" name="product_displayed" as="product_displayed" template="catalog/product/displayed.phtm}}
```

Add your block name `catalog/product_displayed` and set the status to **allowed**

Hope this will sure work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
{{block type="catalog/product" name="product_displayed" as="product_displayed" template="catalog/product/displayed.phtml}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need block then used bellow :

```
{{block type="catalog/product" name="product_displayed" as="product_displayed" template="catalog/product/displayed.phtml}
```

Otherwise simply you added phtml in cms block using this code :

```
{{block type="core/template" name="product_displayed" template="catalog/product/displayed.phtml}
```

Hope this is help of you.